# The command 'Get-AzFunctionApp ' is not working in Azure Automation Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-runbook

I have created a `Runbook` and added below cmdlet

```
   Get-AzFunctionApp  | Stop-AzFunctionApp
```

I get below error

> The term 'Get-AzFunctionApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

I have imported all the below modules but no luck

[image]

After adding 'Az.Functions' I get below error

> Failed
> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SubscriptionId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again. (The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.)

Comment: The title mentions that `Get-AzWebApp` is not working, but in the question you say `Get-AzFunctionApp` is not recognized, could you please clarify it more clear?

Comment: updated the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmdlet `Get-AzFunctionApp` /  `Stop-AzFunctionApp` are included in this module: [Az.Functions](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Functions/2.0.0).

Please import this module and then the functions related operation will work.

Here is an example(please note that add the `-Force` parameter for `Stop-AzFunctionApp`), it works as per my testing:

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName xxx | Stop-AzFunctionApp -Force
```

Comment: okay, maybe I am missing "Connection" , it might be required to have "AzureRunAsConnection"

Comment: @kudlatiger please also remember add the parameter `-Force` for `Stop-AzFunctionApp`, otherwise, it will prompt you to select `yes` or `no` to stop each function.

Comment: @kudlatiger updated the answer with a working example, please let me know if you still have issues about this.

Comment: How do I make all web apps to start and stop in a loop ?

Comment: @kudlatiger do the web apps contain azure function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228616/discussion-between-kudlatiger-and-ivan-yang).

Comment: I m started getting error "Argument passed in is not serializable."

Comment: @kudlatiger, please add an screenshot or detailed command/errors. I can look into it tomorrow:)

Comment: posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222100/argument-passed-in-is-not-serializable-error-comes-while-trying-to-stop-the-ap

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot you posted, it looks like you are missing the [Az.Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.functions/?view=azps-5.5.0) module that contains both the `Get-AzFunctionApp` and `Stop-AzFunctionApp` cmdlets.

To import `Az.Functions` module into your Automation account, do the following:

1. From your Automation account, under **Shared Resources**, select **Modules**.
2. Select **Browse Gallery**.
3. In the search bar, enter the module name (**Az.Functions**).
4. On the PowerShell Module page, select **Import** to import the module into your Automation account.

[image: Import module]

You can also import the module through the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com). Choose the **Azure Automation** tab and select **Deploy to Azure Automation** from here: [Az.Functions](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Functions/2.0.0).